# ActiveRecord return uniq item by title condition nearest distance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have following relation, because same product can exist in multiple stores, so DB stores the same product record in database with different store_id for each store, I also stores the coords for each product, now my query returns duplicate products by title for each store.

For quick fix how can I modify the query to it returns the closest products only and group by the product title maybe. BTW I am using geocode gem and near function to select nearby product near([@lat, @long], 20, order: @sort.blank? ? 'distance' : false)

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :store
end

class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :products
end

ID TITLE   STORE_ID
1  product_1  1
2  product_1  2
3  product_1  3

4  product_2  1
5  product_2  2
6  product_2  3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a misconception in your model. If the same product can be in several stores, then A product does NOT belong to a store. Cause it could be in several.

You should change your associations to a `has_and_belongs_to_many` or a `has_many through` one. But if you really want this query done, you can use the `group` method in your query.
Like `Product.near(...).group(:title)`

You can also filter after in Rails. Assuming it's already an ordered set, something like

```
@products.to_a.uniq(&:title)
```

would work.